# ArrayList won't load when app is restarted

Tags: android, arraylist, save, load, sharedpreferences

I'm quite new to android, and I am having a problem with save and load data.

I am trying to make an app with a save and a load button, these buttons should save 2 ArrayLists with x- and y-coordinates.

I've tried doing it with SharedPreferences and it works until the apps restarts or the screen rotates.

When i take look in the app files the ArrayLists files are in the SharedPreferences folder, but my app will not load those if I press the load button.

Could anyone help we why this does not work when the app is restarted?

this is my load and save code:

```
    public void saveArrayList(ArrayList aList, String s) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(prefs, MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPrefs.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(aList);

    editor.putString(s, json);
    editor.commit();
}

public void loadFloatList(ArrayList aList, String s) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(prefs, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPrefs.getString(s, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Float>>() {
    }.getType();
    aList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible error; you are re-initializing gson and sharedPrefs which then takes a new state with the same key value. you should do this in onCreate.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    json = sharedPrefs.getString(JSON_KEY, "");
    gson = new Gson();
}
```

it is best to use apply() because this save the value(s) of your sharedprefs as instance but commit() do this when the app closes.

```
public void saveArrayList(ArrayList aList) {

    String json = gson.toJson(aList);

    editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString(JSON_KEY, json);
    editor.apply();
}

public void loadFloatList(ArrayList aList, String s) {

    json = sharedPrefs.getString(JSON_KEY, "");
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Float>>() {
    }.getType();
    aList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

note also the PREFS and JSON_KEY are final key values

```
private final String PREFS = "prefs";
private final String JSON_KEY = "json";
private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private String json;
private Gson gson;
```